# Android duration like in css

Tags: android, animation, duration

I just started programming android for about a month already. I also code HTML, CSS & JavaScript.

**Question: Is there a duration code for java when changing a widget property like in CSS?**

For example, if my button `layout_width = 100dp`. Then, in java I made a code that will set it to `200dp`. After clicking the button, it will slowly make the width from `100dp` to `200dp`.

Comment: that's called an animation. find some animation tutorial, and you'll get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android animations can support like this.. you have to use android.transition in head of your class.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html